# Solve the Cauchy Euler Equations. $x^2 y''+7x y'+13y=\ln⁡ x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-sequences, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to solve this question but dont know how to start and what is the method to follow
 Solve the Cauchy Euler Equations.

$$x^2  \frac {d^2 y}{dx^2 }+7x \frac{dy}{dx}+13y=\ln ⁡x$$

Comment: One way to start is to solve the homogeneous ODE by the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$, then proceed via variation of parameters.

Comment: If you are going to use this site you need to learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also we don't just do homework for you.  Your attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^2 y''+7x y'+13y=\ln⁡ x$$
Substitute $x=e^z \implies z=\ln x$

Then 
$$y'=\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{dz}\frac {dz}{dx}=\frac 1 x\frac {dy}{dz}$$
$$y''=\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac 1 {x^2}\frac {dy}{dz}+\frac 1 {x^2}\frac {d^2y}{dz^2}$$
The equation becomes
$$y''+6y'+13y=z$$

can you take it from there ?

Comment: O yes i can do furthur

Comment: @TechAvenue thats great ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Assume $$u=x^{\lambda}$$
$$u^{\prime}=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$$
$$u^{\prime\prime}=\lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}$$